# GitHub actions failing (r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v1) as MASS: Needs R >= 4.3> but only R = 4.2 available?

Tags: github, github-actions

Both GH actions (pkgdown & R-CMD-check) are failing when pushing content to the repo.

For both workflows (pkgdown & R-CMD-check) the run: `r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v1` is failing on "Install Dependencies" with a `call_remote_error: Cannot install packages:` stating `MASS: Needs R >= 4.3.`

However, only R = 4.2 is currently available. And when I view MASS [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html) we see that this actually depends on  R >= 3.3, not 4.3 as stated in my error.

**To Reproduce** 
the two workflows within the repo `.github/workflows/` directory are: 
[R-CMD-check.yaml](https://github.com/udsleeds/openinfra/blob/main/.github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml) - [failed workflow](https://github.com/udsleeds/openinfra/runs/6778250688?check_suite_focus=true#step:16:139)

[pkgdown.yaml](https://github.com/udsleeds/openinfra/blob/main/.github/workflows/pkgdown.yaml)  - [failed workflow](https://github.com/udsleeds/openinfra/runs/6757085709?check_suite_focus=true)

**Expected behavior** 
Checks to run and pass successfully as they have been doing previously ([R-CMD-check](https://github.com/udsleeds/openinfra/runs/6572779390?check_suite_focus=true) [pkgdown](https://github.com/udsleeds/openinfra/actions/runs/2377611589))

At first I thought this will have been a documentation/dependecy listing error, however this has been occuring for the last 14 days now, and this appears to be a [shared issue](https://github.community/t/r-cmd-check-github-action-failing-because-mass-needs-r-4-3/255627).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't share links, but paste a minimal reproducible example directly into the question. Here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.

The issue was using the @v1 versions of `r-lib/actions/...` uses.

These needed to be manually bumped up to @v2.

In doing this two additional errors were created, but these are easily fixable as shown in this [r-lib/actions GitHub issue log](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/issues/575) I created.

I hope this helps if anybody else has this issue.